In React Highchart, Lollipop chart is not rendering
I am using Highcharts v11.4.7 and while trying to render the Lollipop chart, it is throwing below error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Below is the code I am using to import all the required libraries.
import Highcharts, { Options } from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import HighchartLollipop from "highcharts/modules/lollipop";
HighchartLollipop(Highcharts); // Bar chart loads fine if we comment this line

CodeSandbox can be referred to see the error.
I think it was working fine as such in previous versions of highcharts but cant seem to understand what I am doing wrong here..

I don't have the courage to read the docs of this lib, but it seems you need to use HighchartsDumbbell first if you want to use HighchartLollipop, see this answer.
